# Implement Field API Pane Editor into Views

Tags: 7, views, entities, navigation, nodes

I have a View which shows nodes from a content type. I need user to be able to edit only one field from these nodes. I installed [FAPE module](http://drupal.org/project/fape) and read its instructions but cat figure out how to implement it into views. I can't ever find out how links should look. Any help would be appreciated. 10x

Comment: I think they talk a little bit about it in a drupalcon. Did you have the change to see that conference http://www.covenantdesign.com/blog/drupalcon-session-review-whats-new-panels-universe

Comment: Yes, as i remember there fape is only mentioned.....

Answer (score 1):

For editing single-field values in views, there's the [editable fields module](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) rather than FAPE. However, this edits a single row at a time, rather than bulk updating all nodes or entities in the view at the same time.

Comment: That did the job. I only had to remove and rewrite the first IF block in the js because it behaves in a strange way when more then one nodes are shown